# Codeigniter 3 upload file problem: You did not select a file to upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-3

I am new to coding. I am developing a student application system. It requires uploading image and file. Now, I am trying to upload an image. I've been looking for answers here but I couldn't find one that can solve my problem. I've been debugging this for weeks. The field name for the image is 'image_input'. The file name enters the database but the image isn't uploading in the folder.

I'm using PHP version 8. I also added the multipart, made the folder under 777 permission and other solutions here but nothing worked so far. I am not using AJAX.

Controller:

```
        

        if($this->session->logged_in == true){
            
    

            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger">','</div>'); // optional if gusto mo ng css
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('student_num', 'student number', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'first name', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'last name', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('course', 'course', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('year_level', 'year level', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact_num', 'contact number', 'required');
            // $this->form_validation->set_rules('curriculum_eval', 'curriculum evaluation file', 'required');
            // $this->form_validation->set_rules('award_applied', 'academic award', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_sem_gwa', 'first semester GWA', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('second_sem_gwa', 'second semester GWA', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('exception_reason', 'exception reason', 'not required');
            // $this->form_validation->set_rules('image_input', 'image input', 'not required');
            $image_input=$this->input->post('image_input');
            
       
            
            $this->load->library('upload');
 
            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
                $page = "achievers";

                if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/userdashboard/'.$page.'.php'))
                {
                    show_404();
                }

                $data['title'] = "";
                

                $this->load->view('templates/header');
                $this->load->view('userdashboard/'.$page, $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');

            }
            else {
                
                $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'pdf|jpg|png';
                
                $image_input = "image_input";
                $this->load->library("upload", $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($image_input))
                {
                        $imageError = array('imageError' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                        print_r($imageError);
                }
                else
                {
                    
                    $file_name = $this->upload->data('file_name'); 
                    $data = array('image_input' => $file_name);

                    $this->Posts_model->insert_achievers();
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('achievers_added', 'Your application is received.');
                    redirect('user_home_page'); 

                    
                }
                
        
            }
        }
        else {
            redirect(base_url());
        }
```

View:

```
                    <div class="col-md-8 .col-md-4 .col-lg-6">
                        
                        <?php echo form_open_multipart('UserDashboard/achievers');?>
                        
                        <form method="post" action="<?=base_url('UserDashboard/achievers') ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="student_num" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-black ml-2"><b>Student&nbsp;Number</b></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                  <input type="text" name="student_num" class="form-control" 
                                    placeholder="e.g. 2019-00000-TG-0" id="student_num" value="<?= set_value('student_num'); ?>">
                                     <span class="invalid-feedback"></span>
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="first_name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-black ml-2"><b>First Name</b></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-7">
                                  <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Enter your first name" class="form-control" value="<?= set_value('first_name'); ?>">
                                  <span class="invalid-feedback"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="last_name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-black ml-2"><b>Last Name</b></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-7">
                                  <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Enter your last name" class="form-control" value="<?= set_value('last_name'); ?>">
                                  <span class="invalid-feedback"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="email_address" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-black ml-2"><b>Email Address</b></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-7">
                                  <input type="email" name="email_address" placeholder="e.g. name@gmail.com" class="form-control" value="<?= set_value('email_address'); ?>">
                                  <span class="invalid-feedback"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="course" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-black ml-2"><b>Course</b></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                      <select type="course" name="course" class=" btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" value="<?= set_value('course'); ?>" placeholder="Select Course" >
                          
                                          <option value="" class="dropdown-item">Select Course</option>
                                          <option value="BSA" class="dropdown-item">BSA</option>                               
                                          <option value="BSECE" class="dropdown-item">BSECE</option>                            
                                          <option value="BSME" class="dropdown-item">BSME</option>                          
                                          

                                    <span class="invalid-feedback"><?= $course_err ?></span>
                                    </select>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="year_level" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-black ml-2"><b>Year&nbsp;Level</b></label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <select type="button" name="year_level" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" value="<?= set_value('year_level'); ?>" placeholder="Select Year Level">
                          
                                              <option value="" class="dropdown-item">Select Year Level</option>
                                              <option value="first_year" class="dropdown-item">1st Year</option>
                                      
                                              <span class="invalid-feedback" class="dropdown-item"></span>

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="contact_num" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-black ml-2"><b>Contact&nbsp;Number</b></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                  <input type="text" name="contact_num" placeholder="e.g. +639xxxxxxxxx"  class="form-control " value="<?= set_value('contact_num'); ?>"></input>
                                  <span class="invalid-feedback"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                            
                                    <label for="curriculum_eval" class="col-sm-2 form-label text-black ml-2"><b>Curriculum Evaluation&nbsp;</b>(.pdf)</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        
                                          <input type="file" name="curriculum_eval" class="" value="<?= set_value('curriculum_eval'); ?>"></input>
                                          
                                            <span class="invalid-feedback"></span>
                                        </div>
                               
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="award_applied" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-black ml-2"><b>Award Applied</b></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9 ">
                                    <select type="course" name="award_applied" class=" btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" value="<?= set_value('award_applied'); ?>"
                                    placeholder="Select Course" >
                        
                                        <option value="" class="dropdown-item">Select Award</option>
                                        <option value="achiever_award" class="dropdown-item">Achiever's Award</option>                             
                                        <!-- <option value="academic_excellence" class="dropdown-item">Academic Excellence (4th/5th yr only)</option>                           -->
                                        

                                    <span class="invalid-feedback"><?= $award_applied_err ?></span>
                                    </select>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="first_sem_gwa" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-black ml-2"><b>1st&nbsp;Sem&nbsp;GWA</b></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                  <input type="text" name="first_sem_gwa" placeholder="e.g. 1.00" class="form-control" value="<?= set_value('first_sem_gwa'); ?>"></input>
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="second_sem_gwa" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-black ml-2"><b>2nd&nbsp;Sem&nbsp;GWA</b></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                  <input type="text" name="second_sem_gwa" placeholder="e.g. 1.00" class="form-control" value="<?= set_value('second_sem_gwa'); ?>"></input>
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group row">
                           
                            <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-leftjustify-content-between col-lg-6 mb-5">
                                <label for="image_input" class=" col-form-label text-black ml-2"><b>Upload&nbsp;your&nbsp;2x2&nbsp;photo</b></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="file" name="image_input" class="form-control" value="<?= set_value('image_input'); ?>"></input>
                                  <div class="text-danger">
                                    
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                           
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-sm-10 text-center">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary " name="submit" value="Submit Application"></input>
                                    <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>user_home_page" class="btn btn-secondary text-white">Cancel</a>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </form>
                    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Model:

```
public function insert_achievers()
    {
        $data = array(
            'student_num' => $this->input->post('student_num'),
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'slug' => url_title($this->input->post('student_num'), '-', true),
            'email_address' => $this->input->post('email_address'),
            'course' => $this->input->post('course'),
            'year_level' => $this->input->post('year_level'),
            'contact_num' => $this->input->post('contact_num'),
            'curriculum_eval' => $this->input->post('curriculum_eval'),
            'award_applied' => $this->input->post('award_applied'),
            'first_sem_gwa' => $this->input->post('first_sem_gwa'),
            'second_sem_gwa' => $this->input->post('second_sem_gwa'),
            'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
            'exception_reason' => $this->input->post('exception_reason'),
            'image_input' => $this->input->post('image_input')
        );

        
        return $this->db->insert('student_applicants', $data); 
    }
```

The error is:

Array ( [imageError] =>
You did not select a file to upload.

)

Comment: Please show us the upload form as well. Also, where and when exactly do you see that error? Please post the full error message. Are you uploading the file using JS (Ajax) or is it a "normal" form submission? We need more context.

Comment: Hello! Sorry, I'm new in posting questions here. I added some details in my question. It is a normal form submission, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See this if it helps your problem
send the image using multipart form type
and at the controller level use the following

```
if ($this->input->method(true) == 'POST') {
  if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {
    $config['upload_path']          = './public/uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size']             = 2048;
    $config['file_name'] = time() . $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $config['file_name'] = $this->security->sanitize_filename($config['file_name']);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
      return $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_status_header(200)
        ->set_output(json_encode(
          array(
            'status' => false,
            'data' => [],
            'error' => $this->upload->display_errors()
          )
        ));
    }
    $base = base_url('/public/uploads/');
    $file_name = $base . $this->upload->data('file_name');}}
```

Comment: Hello! I already solved the upload problem. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Hello @hufflepuffed please how did you solve the issue!? Am facing the same issue with CodeIgneter 3

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the upload problem. I added the form_open in the view page that's why I got the error even though I have the form_open_multipart. Thanks for your answers anyway!